# Best/average/worst-case complexity for cryptography

Tags: complexity

I understand that the complexity of a problem can be measured by it's best-case, average-case, or worst-case complexity. Am I correct in thinking that, for cryptographic purposes, each of these is of interest?:

**Best-case:** If we can find a problem whose best-case complexity is high, then it will be high for all instances of that problem, so this problem would be great to base a cryptosystem on.

**Worst-case:** If a problem has high complexity in the worst case, we could look for a large set of instances for which the problem has worst-case complexity, and randomly select keys from this set.

**Average-case:** Wikipedia says that average-case complexity analysis can be used to generate hard instances of a problem.

There does seem to be some conflicting opinions between the best measure of complexity. For example, I have read that NP-complete problems (using worst-case) are desirable for the reason above, but I have also read that they are undesirable because we want the problem to be hard over random inputs.

Comment: "random inputs" -> "sufficiently random inputs" may explain it.

Comment: Since the best case is the case where you guess the correct key immediately, the defender won't have an advantage over the attacker and thus a high best-case complexity implies an unusable system.